# Click twice to check Radio Button?

Tags: android, radio-button

I am trying to build a test application and I am using Radio buttons for the choices A,B,C,D. I am trying to calculate the result -> for example when press A increment 1, when press B increment 2 and so on. I was using Radio Group at first but I understood that if the user try to change the answer to his question from A to B the incremented result will be 3, not 2 as expected. So I switched to Radio Buttons and I try the following code:

```
      rb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new 
         android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener (){ 

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            i++;
            if(rb2.isChecked())
            { 
                i--;
                rb2.setChecked(false);                  
            }

        }
            });

    rb2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener (){


        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            i++;

            if(rb1.isChecked())
            { 
                i--;
                rb2.setChecked(false);                          
            }
        }
            });
```

And now the second Radio Button have to be clicked twice in order to be checked. Is this a bug and could it be fixed. I need the Buttons to change state after the first click. All ideas and advice will be welcomed. Thank you.

Comment: use switch case to get which radio button is checked & based on that assign the value.

Comment: I tried that with the radio group but it still assigned both values.

Comment: I have litttle confusion about your question..? First of all you have two radio button A and B, when press on A, you want to increment the number by 1, and when press on B you want to increment the number 2 right..? What is the use of increment when you are using it for one instance i.e one time, because when you change it to 1 to 2 only 2 should increment..It is quite confusing can you please elobarate me with scenario

Comment: what are you trying to do with the i? could you explain a little bit more?

Comment: I will try to explain it better. For example you have 10 questions with 2 choice A,B each. When you press A you increment CRAZY++, when you press B you increment NORMAL++. At the end of the quiz you will probably have CRAZY = 3, NORMAL = 7. But now with that code if the user tries to change his answer from A to B, he has to click twice on B (for it to be checked) which will result in adding 2 (not 1) to the final result. I was asking how to remove that double click and the button to change state immediately after the first click? The result may be NORMAL=8, CRAZY=6 but this is not real result.

Comment: @PetroslavBenchovsky But for rb2 you need to increment two right, but why i++

Answer (score 1):

You can change your code to use a switch statement (as suggested in one of the comments) but if you want to continue with what you have, and to answer your question.  In your code for rb2, you are saying that if rb1 is checked set rb2 to false.  So, if you click rb1 (and it is now checked/pushed) and you click rb2 the first time you uncheck it, the 2nd time it stays checked.

So sticking with your coding style and procedure:

```
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
            boolean isChecked) {
        i++;

        if(rb1.isChecked())
        { 
            i--;
            rb2.setChecked(false);                          
        }
    }
```

should be:

```
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
            boolean isChecked) {
        i++;

        if(isChecked && rb1.isChecked())
        { 
            i--;
            rb1.setChecked(false);                          
        }

        rb2.setChecked(isChecked);
    }
```

Make a similar change to your rb1 method.

Comment: it still needs a second click to be changed to Checked again. First click it uncheckes the rb1, and after the second click rb2 becomes checked. Does still incrementing twice. Could you give me some pointers on how it will be done with a switch statement?

Comment: oh, that's interesting.  The "setChecked" is calling teh "onCheckedChanged".  I didn't catch that this would happen.  So when you check a different button, it is "checked" then you force an uncheck on the alternate button, which in-turn unchecks what you just did.  See my edits.  As for switching to switch statement, each  of your onCheckedChanged overrides are the same, but working on a different button. You can switch on the buttonView.